# Multiple sheets query

Tags: google-sheets

I have a master file where I compile data from other employees 
The file has 30 sheets and on that compiles them,
I'm using `=Query` and it's a marvellous tool however if someone calls in sick or is in a vacation I have to manually edit the formula to exclude their sheet and add it again when they come back because the query will render an error if there is no data on their sheets.

Is there a way where It can be done dynamically?

Comment: How do you aggregate the information from the different sheets? Without this information it's not possible to give you accurate help.

Comment: I don't have access to my pc at the moment I will rey to share a sample sheet of how it looks like and I think it would explain what my problem is

Comment: **edit your question and include your `QUERY` formula for further assistance**

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give you exact advice since we don't know how you are aggregating your data, but what I usually would do is to wrap my queries with [IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en). If the query is successful it won't change anything, but if it fails it will catch the error and display either nothing or whatever you tell it to display.

Answer (score 0):

change your `QUERY` formula from this:

```
=QUERY({Sheet1!A:C,
        Sheet2!A:C}, "select *")
```

to this:

```
=QUERY({IFERROR(Sheet1!A:C, {"","",""}),
        IFERROR(Sheet2!A:C, {"","",""})}, "select * where Col1 is not null")
```